# Текстовый поиск по блокам с добавлением класса

Tags: jquery, search, text

Нужен текстовый поиск, который при совпадении будет добавлять класс блоку в котором нашлось совпадение, Нашел как искать, но как тут добавить класс?

```
var target = search.val().toLowerCase();
$('.some').each(function(){
    var str = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    var position = 0;
    while (true) {
        var found = str.indexOf(target.toLowerCase(), position);
        if (found == -1) break;
        pos = found + 1;
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь `addClass`:

```js
var target = "bbb";
$('.some').each(function(index) {
  var str = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
  if (str.indexOf(target.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
    $(this).addClass("newclass");
  }
});
$(".newclass").css('color', "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some">aaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
<div class="some">aaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
<div class="some">aaaabbbaaaaa</div>
<div class="some">aaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
<div class="some">aaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```